# How to send UDP packet in a wireless network from multi-host simultaneously in INET/Veins_inet

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

Greeting all,

I am trying to edit Veins_inet (square example)to the following scenario:

node#1,2 send UDP packet to node#0 at time 15s and stop sending at 18s.
but when I do that the UDP packet not sent simultaneously!

How can I make the two node target node#0 simultaneously?

here part of .ini file

```
# UDPBasicApp
MyScenario.node[1..2].numUdpApps = 2
MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[0].typename = "UDPBasicApp"
MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[0].destAddresses = "224.0.0.1"
MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[0].multicastInterface = "wlan0"
MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[0].joinLocalMulticastGroups = true
#MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[0].localPort = 9001
MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[0].destPort = 9001
MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[0].messageLength = 100B
MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[0].startTime = uniform(0s, 5s)
MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[0].sendInterval = 5s #uniform(0.01s, 0.05s)

#atttack

MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[1].typename = "UDPBasicApp"
#MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[1].destAddresses = "224.0.0.1"
MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[1].multicastInterface = "wlan0"
MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[1].joinLocalMulticastGroups = true
# MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[1].localPort = 9001
MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[1].destAddresses = "node[0]"
MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[1].destPort = 9001
MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[1].messageLength = 100B
MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[1].startTime = 15s #uniform(0s, 5s)
MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[1].stopTime = 18s 
MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[1].sendInterval = 0.01s #uniform(0.01s, 0.05s)
MyScenario.node[1..2].udpApp[1].packetName = "attack"
```

Any help will be very appreciated to help me to move forward in my project

Comment: In the Veins_INET example of Veins 5a1, cars are regular INET hosts (only with special mobility). Just configure them like you would in any plain INET simulation.

Comment: Thanks for replay. After I compare my code with some INET example which sent packet simultaneously, I found that Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium send ACK so that cause time difference between packets. Also, I tried to use different radioMedium, like IRadioMedium. now the two packets sent at the same time and no more ACK. But I don't know if using IRadioMedium instead of Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium is correct option? because VANET uses IEEE 802.11 standards. furthermore, is the using IRadioMedium affect my scenario ?! because I want to make victim node out of reachable after receiving some packets.